# AS2: rollover on attached movieclip

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, rollover

The following is the chunk of my code that is attaching a movieclip (from timeline), tracing thisDot works so it is not the variable which is a problem but there is no rollover applied to the attached movieclip.

```
    var dot_name:String = new String(Graphs[s]._name+"_dot"+i);
    var dotObj:Object = new Object();
    if (prevX != undefined) {
        dotObj._x = newX;
    } else {
        dotObj._x = 0;
    }
    dotObj._y = Slide_y;
    Graphs[s].chart.attachMovie("graph_dot",dot_name,Graphs[s].chart.getNextHighestDepth(),dotObj);
    eval(thisDot=Graphs[s]+".chart."+dot_name);
    Graphs_dots[s].push(thisDot);
    thisDot.onRollOver = function () {
        trace(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that this row:

```
eval(thisDot=Graphs[s]+".chart."+dot_name);
```

should be this instead?

```
thisDot=eval(Graphs[s]+".chart."+dot_name);
```

Comment: Actually your right that worked... strange considering thisDot was tracing fine before. Thanks once again Dain!